# Internal Microphone Disabled Upon Using Earbuds

Tags: microphone, input

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and I have been using Discord (Voice-chat website).  When I do not have earbuds plugged in, I can hear my friends and they can hear me, but when I plug in earbuds, I can still hear them, but they can no longer hear me.  When I check the System Settings > Sound > Input, I see my "Internal Microphone" option renaming to "Microphone."  I suspect Ubuntu thinks my earbuds have both output and input capability, but it doesn't.  How do I stop Ubuntu from automatically making this switch?  I can't seem to manually go back to "Internal Microphone" because that option doesn't appear when plugging in earbuds.

Thanks!